# Why would my Power BI connection to an Oracle server show only empty tables?

Tags: oracle, powerbi

I was able to connect to an Oracle server through Power BI, but after I signed in with my read only credentials, all the tables are empty. I click on the folder and there's nothing there.
[image]

Comment: So some of the tables are populated? Or none of them?

Comment: None of the columns are populated.